# Error during compilation using make, problem with C++/Gnu version?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I am trying to compile a library. I used Cmake and it worked saying:

> "LibraryName requires the language dialect "CXX17", but CMake does not know the compile flags to use to enable it.

After that I compiled using `make`:but it gives the following errors in output (while compiling some `cpp` files):

```
    cc1: warning: command line option ‘-fpermissive’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]

    env.hpp:10:1: warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
         enum class PlacementMethod {
        
    alltoallv.cpp:19:7: error: ‘AlltoallvMethod’ is not a class or namespace
           if (AlltoallvMethod::NONE == environment::alltoallv) {
        
    alltoallv.cpp:44:8: error: ‘AlltoallvMethod’ is not a class or namespace
           case AlltoallvMethod::AUTO: {
       
    alltoallv.cpp:43:10: warning: enumeration value ‘AUTO’ not handled in switch [-Wswitch-enum]
        
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tempi.dir/src/alltoallv.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tempi.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I solve this?

I cannot modify my environment or use "sudo" command, because I'm working on a public cluster and I do not own those privileges.

CMake output:

```
../../cmake-3.21.1-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake ..
-- Build type: Release
-- GIT_REFSPEC=refs/heads/master
-- GIT_HASH=fe16ae7692da83e9cd247782f596a46a1d010699
-- GIT_LOCAL_CHANGES=DIRTY
-- MPI include dir: /opt/ohpc/pub/mpi/openmpi-gnu/1.10.7/include
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- -march=native detected
-- define TEMPI_ENABLE_KAHIP
-- OpenMP support detected
-- -march=native detected
-- nvToolsExt found: /hpc/share/tools/cuda/10.2.89/lib64/libnvToolsExt.so
-- nvidia-ml found: /hpc/share/tools/cuda/10.2.89/lib64/stubs/libnvidia-ml.so
-- Configuring done
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Target "tempi" requires the language dialect "CXX17" , but CMake does not
  know the compile flags to use to enable it.


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

Comment: What versions of GCC and CMake are you using?

Comment: Your build system is likely ancient since gcc is telling you to enable C++11.

Comment: gcc --version output: gcc (GCC) 8.3.0, and I used the last CMake version available in their site: 3.21

Comment: that's weird CMake should know how to set  `-std=c++17`, maybe try to set `CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17` manually before building

Comment: I added "export CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17" before running Cmake, now I'm compiling. I will edit in 1-2 min to say if this worked

Comment: CMake from 3.8 upwards should be able to do that itself. Make sure that cmake finds the right the g++ version. So if it doesn't detect the compiler you can just set the environment variable `CXX` to full path of the g++ version you want to use.

Comment: Ok I tried without success. Can you please tell me how to "make sure that cmake finds the right g++ version"?

Comment: @0abc0cba0 can you add the first like 30 lines of output from cmake when configuring the project to your question?

Comment: Absolutely I edit with the full output.

Comment: weird, normally I would've assumed it would print the versions of the compiler it detected. Anyway, you should try to set the env variable `CC` to the gcc executable you want to use and `CXX` to the g++ version you want to use

Comment: Thank you so much, I solved running Cmake and specifying the version.

Comment: The CXX standard used by CMake can be either set by editing the `CMakeLists.txt` file `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` or through the command line option `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17`.

Comment: Thank you, however also using: `../../cmake-3.21.1-linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=pathto/gcc/8.3.0/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=pathto/gcc/8.3.0/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 ..` I still get same errors...

Answer (score 0):

"alltoallv.cpp:19:7: error: ‘AlltoallvMethod’ is not a class or namespace", so please check here to find the reason.

Comment: the reason is in the error log just above it, this answer doesn't address the root cause also visible in the question.